# Block internet browser from one user

Tags: networking, internet

I was wondering if there is a way to block the internet tab (applications/internet) from one user.  I am trying to allow games to use the internet but not allow the use of browser.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the Parental Controls application. There is a detailed guide [here](http://www.liberiangeek.net/2011/03/parental-control-ubuntu-11-04-natty-narwhal/) on how to install and run it.

If you select the user that you want to limit, and choose to leave the "browser" option as off 24/7 then that should do the trick.